# I have problems on executing a If statement in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, windows-10, ms-office

I'm getting a syntax error at the below code, Please do help me soon

Thanks

```
Set rng = Range("AM4:AM" & Lastrow)
rng.Formula = "=IF(P4="Y",1,0)"  //I need to execute this statement//
```

[I have attached the screen shot of the error message with the whole code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByC2x.png)

Answer (score 2):

Instead, try using two double-quotes around the Y:

```
rng.Formula = "=IF(P4=""Y"",1,0)"
```

If you want to include a (double) quote inside a string, you need to do this, otherwise it looks like you are ending the string, then VBA gets confused when it gets to Y